# Take results of stored procedure and use in SQL query in my code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Due to some bad database design I've had to go through a bunch of steps to filter the results I'm looking for using a Stored Procedure and Table-valued Function.  Now that I have the SP working properly and returning the records I want, I need to take those matches and work them back into the main sql query in my code behind.

So, I've got my stored procedure called usp_County which returns multiple records, then I have my normal query in code behind like this:

```
Select * From MyTable Where Name = @Name AND Address = @Address and so on.
```

Is there some (hopefully simple) way to work in my results from the stored procedure?  Something along the lines of this maybe?

```
Select * From MyTable Where (dbo.usp_County(@county) AND Name = @Name AND Address = @Address and so on.
```

The results I'm trying to find are all in the same table that the SP is running against, just using the SP and this query to further filter.

For example, I want to search/query based on:

```
Name1   Address1    County(this is already populated by records through the SP)
```

**Edit**

My attempt at creating temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #spResults (id int, Counties varchar(max))
INSERT INTO #spResults (id, Counties)
EXEC usp_County '@county'

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return sproc data into a temp table (sproc output data types must match table definition), then join to the temp table for the extra data & to apply your filter.

```
CREATE TABLE #spResults
(col1, col2, col3..)

INSERT INTO #spResults
EXEC sprocName(@Param)

SELECT * FROM MyTable JOIN #spResults ON <Cond>
```

Comment: Could I trouble you to fill in a few blanks for me, I'm very new at this.  I assume I'm creating another sproc, correct?   I'm trying to create it but getting various errors.  I've added my work so far to original question.  In the original sproc there are only two values returned when run: id which is set at int and Counties  which is varchar(max), processed bit (not sure if the processed bit part matters).

Comment: this is my current error BTW: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Make sure in your sproc you have SET NOCOUNT ON at the top (rowcounts being printed messes up output data). Other than that if you are sure the table definition matches the output, it should work!